# XNA 4 Song.fromUri containing Spaces

Tags: xna, uri, xna-4.0

Hey,
When trying to load a Song (via Uri) (`Song.fromUri()`) from my HDD (file:///...), The Mediaplayer throws a Exception.
After a bit of googling i found out, that this Problem is related to Spaces in the Uri, so i tried escaping it:

`Uri.escapeUriString()` don't work, the Result is a new Uri Object, containing null. Same Thing on `uri.escapeDataString()` or different Solutions.

Is there an easier way to load an external mp3 into XNA?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest method would be to use reflection to get access to this internal constructor:

```
internal Song(string name, string filename, int duration);
```

Here is some code that does just that:

```
var ctor = typeof(Song).GetConstructor(
        BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance, null,
        new[] { typeof(string), typeof(string), typeof(int) }, null);
song = (Song)ctor.Invoke(new object[] { "name", @"C:\My Music\Blah.mp3", 0 });
```

Obviously this is not really ideal. I do not think the XNA runtime does minor-version updates (meaning that if your game uses XNA 4.0, it is always the same runtime), but I do not know for sure. By using an internal constructor your game is entirely at the mercy of binary updates by Microsoft. You probably want a nice big exception handler on that.

Additionally, I found that some MP3 files would (literally) silently fail to play. Also the `Duration` property is obviously not filled in by this method.

(Obviously this is Windows-only code. But you can't really access random bits of the filesystem like this on WP7 or Xbox anyway.)

Comment: Reflections never came in my mind. Thanks, trying it that way!