# How do you Load an MP3 file without actually using the Content class?

Tags: c#, xna, loading

I am a beginner at Programming with C Sharp, and I am using the XNA SDK. I am trying to make a simple game to help my fellow classmates with studying for school, and I decided I would like it if there was some way to have them put music they want to listen to while playing the game inside of a file, and have the game automatically Load the music files, and play them in a playlist.

So far, I am able to get the game to detect whether the files are music, by detecting whether the file path name Contains(".mp3") , but I am trying to actually load the file name into a list of type Song, using a for Loop. The code looks like this.

(Declaration)

```
List<Song> songsToPlay;
string[] fileNames
```

(Initialize)

```
fileNames[] = Directory.GetFiles(".\Music")
```

(LoadContent)

```
for (int i = 0; i < fileNames.Count(); i++)
{
      if (fileNames[i].Contains(".mp3")
      {
          songsToPlay.Add(fileNames[i]);
      }
}
```

I have been trying to find a way to add a whole folder to the Content Directory, and have it do something more like

```
for (int i = 0; i < fileNames.Count(); i++)
{
    songsToPlay.Add(Content.Load<Song>("fileNames[i]") 
}
```

I have been unable to find some way to do this... Does anyone know how to make this work, or a better way to do this?

Answer (score 3):

If you have your files in your project content, you should use [the `ContentManager` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.content.contentmanager.aspx).  It gives you more than just file loading.  For example you can [use `Content.Unload` to unload all your data](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.content.contentmanager.unload.aspx) when you're no longer using it.

There is no need to avoid that class.  [This page has an example](http://danielsaidi.wordpress.com/2010/01/26/xna-load-all-content-files-in-a-folder/) showing exactly what you're trying to do:

```
public static Dictionary<string, T> LoadContent<T>(
    this ContentManager contentManager, string contentFolder)
{
   var dir = new DirectoryInfo(contentManager.RootDirectory
       + "\\" + contentFolder);
   if (!dir.Exists)
      throw new DirectoryNotFoundException();

   var result = new Dictionary<string, T>();

   foreach (FileInfo file in dir.GetFiles("*.mp3"))
   {
      string key = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file.Name);

      result[key] = contentManager.Load<T>(
          contentManager.RootDirectory + "/" + contentFolder + "/" + key);
   }

   return result;
}
```

You can use it like this:

```
var songs = Content.LoadContent<Song>("Songs");
```

#### Slight improvement to this code...

Once you get the above code working, I also suggest you make a slight change:

```
var dir = new DirectoryInfo(
    System.IO.Path.Combine(contentManager.RootDirectory, contentFolder));
```

You shouldn't manually build paths via string concatenation when you can possibly avoid it.  I don't know that you can do the same for `ContentManager` paths tho, so you might have to stick with string concatenation for that case.

#### Edit: Too many constructs you haven't used in class yet

Since you haven't used [extension methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx) or [the `static` keyword](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/98f28cdx.aspx) in your class yet, and probably haven't used dictionaries, here's a simpler way to do this:

```
string contentFolder = "Music";
var dir = new DirectoryInfo(Content.RootDirectory + "\\" + contentFolder);

if (!dir.Exists)
{
    // Todo: Display a message to the user instead?
    throw new DirectoryNotFoundException();
}

string[] files = dir.GetFiles("*.mp3");

for (int i = 0; i < files.Count(); ++i)
{
    FileInfo file = files[i];
    string key = System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file.Name);

    var song = Content.Load<Song>(
        Content.RootDirectory + "/" + contentFolder + "/" + key);

    songsToPlay.Add(song);
}
```

#### Edit2: Some explanation of this second code sample

[The `DirectoryInfo` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directoryinfo.aspx) lets you load up a directory so you can enumerate all the files in it.

[The `GetFiles` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8he88b63.aspx) on `DirectoryInfo` lets you enumerate files using a wildcard style pattern matching.  Wildcard pattern matching for files means that when given these patterns:

- `*.*` - you are looking for files named `<anything>.<anything>`
- `*.mp3` - you are looking for `<anything>.mp3`

`throw` means throwing an exception.  This will deliberately stop executing code and display a good error message ("directory not found") and a line number.  [There is a *lot* to learn about exception handling](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229014.aspx), so I won't try to do it justice with a description here.

[`GetFileNameWithoutExtension`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfilenamewithoutextension.aspx) should be obvious because it is well named.

> `Content.RootDirectory + "/" + contentFolder + "/" + key`

That last little bit of code will build up a string containing the content root directory, the sub-directory of your songs, and each file name, using a name it can understand (since it doesn't know about filename extensions).

[`var`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383973.aspx) means "whatever type I assign to it".  It is a short-cut.  For example, instead of typing:

```
List<string> someList = new List<string>();
```

You type:

```
var someList = new List<string>();
```

`var` has to know what type is on the right-hand-side of the assignment.  It is useful because you can [avoid repeating yourself](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself).

Using `var` doesn't bestow any magical abilities to the variable though.  You won't be able to assign a variable of a different type once you've declared the variable.  It is just a short-cut for the exact same functionality.

Comment: I have a slight problem with this... I have only been learning how to program for a few months... I am in a computer programming class, and So far we have never actually talked about how to use a Static Field, and we have never gone into much detail about how to use methods to return a value. I have tried understanding this, and I got a little bit, but I am still lost... Maybe if there was some way I could understand how this actually works a little bit more in-depth...

Comment: @MatthewCrandall: This is a method, not a field.  Tho it is static.  It is also [an extension method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx).  I'll write up a modified version that fits within your existing teachings tho :)

Comment: Thank you... I always heard it as a Static field. I know what a Method is, but since it was Static, and I dont understand what Static actually does, or what it is, I just named it a Static Field. I have just never worked with the ContentManager, RootDirectory, or the Dictionary, so I just have no clue what was truly going on... maybe if i could get some more explanation as to how it works, I could actually understand what is happening :)

Comment: @MatthewCrandall: Will do!  I've posted a version of the code that is more like your original code now.  Will try to add some explanation too.

Comment: @MatthewCrandall: Okay done adding my explanations.  Let me know if I confused you more, or if you have questions I didn't answer :)  Also, feel free to follow the `extension methods` or `static` link I put in my answer to read a bit more about them.

Comment: I actually followed most of that, and i plan on doing some readin up on both of those... I have tried adding all this into the LoadContent method, but it is returning with a few errors. I wonder if I am missing something else? It says it "Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'System.IO.FileInfo' . It has that same error, later on, but in reverse, where it cant convert from System.IO.FileInfo[] to string[]... the two errors are at (respectively) "string[] files = dir.GetFiles("*mp3"); and later on at "FileInfo file = files[i];

Comment: I have just been looking through the code. The dir.GetFile("*.mp3") Returns an array of files, of type System.IO.FileInfo[], not as a string, so it also needs some conversion from System.IO.FileInfo[] int a string[]. I have tried tweaking it, adding a .ToString() at the end of the statement, but then it says cant convert type string to type string[], so i wonder if i need to save it as a string, and then use a split to break the string into an array, and then load the file from that string array, instead of trying to give a value of type string[] a DirectoryInfo[]....

Comment: @MatthewCrandall: I probably screwed that part up cause I wasn't actually writing the code in the compiler.  `FileInfo[]` should be fine for the variable `files`.

Comment: Yeah. I figured out the FileInfo would work, all by myself... no problem its understandable. Now, I have another issue. Apparently, CSharp can't actually load direct MP3's, at least, in the way we are trying to get it to work. It keeps saying "Error, CSharp Can Not open the file. Are you sure you are using the right uploader?"... Is there some way to check if there are MP3's, convert them to XNBs'. Normally, when I load sound, I manually add it into the Content References, and it converts it automatically. I wonder if I need to programmatically convert from MP3 to XNB, to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`Song.FromUri`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.media.song.fromuri.aspx) method:

```
Song.FromUri("audio name", new Uri(@"C:\audio.mp3"));
```

The filepath can't contain spaces!

See here for a workaround: [XNA 4 Song.fromUri containing Spaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5813657/xna-4-song-fromuri-containing-spaces)