# Converting a Stream to a Song class?

Tags: c#, xna, stream, mp3, media-player

I'm trying to open a file from a dialog, then play it with the MediaPlayer in XNA, but, my opener opens the file as a Stream class, and I have no idea how to convert it to a Song class, so I can play it with the MediaPlayer, any help?

```
Stream myStream = null;
OpenFileDialog openFileDialog1 = new OpenFileDialog();

openFileDialog1.InitialDirectory = "c:\\";
openFileDialog1.Filter = "mp3 files (*.mp3)|*.mp3|All files (*.*)|*.*";
openFileDialog1.FilterIndex = 2;
openFileDialog1.RestoreDirectory = true;

if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK) {
    try {
        if ((myStream = openFileDialog1.OpenFile()) != null) {
            using (myStream) {

            }
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        MessageBox.Show("Error: Could not read file from disk. Original error: " + ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you attempted a google search on your own ..?

Comment: do you have any existing code that you can show in regards to what you are doing

Comment: I edited my OP to show my code to get the dialog open.

Comment: Yeah, that's where I need to play the song, that's my question afterall.

Comment: Yes, I can play files, but the only way I know how to play files are to put them in the content pipeline, and I want to open them with the open file dialog.

Comment: you didn't specify that in your original question I will change my answer to provide an example give me one sec

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do it that way. XNA hands off music playback to an internal media player component. It cannot load music from a `Stream` (if I had to guess, it probably implements its own streaming). What it *can* do is load a music file, given a file name.

You could do something like this:

```
Song mySong = Song.FromUri(@"file:///" + openFileDialog1.FileName);
```

It's worth pointing out that there is a known bug if the path to your file contains a space. But there is an internal method that you could use that takes a file name directly and doesn't exhibit the bug - I discuss how to use it in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5829463/165500). It is:

```
internal Song(string name, string filename, int duration);
```

It's worth pointing out that this is pretty much the same thing that the content pipeline does. If you look at the `.xnb` file that it produces for a Song, it is tiny - just a few bytes. And all it contains is the filename of the song to load. The song file itself is just copied in separately.

Answer (score 0):

Their API appears to provide [read only access to resources](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd254868). More Microsoft "security" and  "safety" concerns (translation, DRM and open access issues.)

Short answer, it doesn't look like you can using solely their API.

In code, all things are possible. You can do this...but you would probably have to implement an [ADAPTER](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adapter_pattern) that goes to their documented API. Since Song is sealed and not an interface, they're obviously trying to be proprietary and keep you from doing this. Easily dealt with with [.NET Reflector](http://www.reflector.net/), but this'll turn into a pain. You'll have to define your own interface and convert between the two. As they change their internals your code will break, and you'll have to figure out how to write to the MediaLibrary and all that.

Basically, if you don't know what you're doing, you probably can't. If you do, this is probably a giant pain. If you can find another library (e.g. you're targeting Windows desktops), you might be better off going in that direction.