# Play song from computer during runtime

Tags: c#, xna, media-player

I'm working on a small project that will later help me create a game. What I'm trying to achieve is the ability to play a game from a path on the player's computer. The path is known but I couldn't find any way to achieve playing a song that's not from the content path.

I'm also not talking about changing the content path's root directory, as the song won't load with LoadContent, it will load while the game is already on. If I can't do that I'll have to go back to developing games with Windows Forms which I'm not a fan of..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
    System.IO.FileStream fs = new System.IO.FileStream(@"C:\Myfile.wav", System.IO.FileMode.Open);
    SoundEffect mysound = SoundEffect.FromStream(fs);
    fs.Dispose();
```

@"C:\Myfile.wav" can be a relative or absolute path. Not sure about MP3's or others.

Worst case scenario, just embed the [FMod Ex](http://www.fmod.org/fmod-downloads.html) soundsystem into your XNA game.

Comment: thanks, will try fmod ex as I need more than the capabilities of SoundEffect

Answer (score 1):

You can create an instance of `Song` from a file on disk (a plain MP3 file, instead of something that has been through the content pipeline) using the `Song.FromUri` method ([MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.media.song.fromuri.aspx)).

Of course, there are some caveats with that method - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5829463/165500) for details and an alternate way of creating `Song` objects from files on disk (using reflection).

(Finally, it's worth pointing out that the methods you were using with WinForms can probably be safely used in an XNA game, if you'd like to stick with those.)